# How to find the earliest data that closest to the specified date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Some business data has a `create_on` column to indicate the creation date, and I want to find the earliest data that closest to the specified date. How do I write the sql? I'm using postgres database.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (
  id int primary key,
  create_on date not null
  -- ignore other columns
);
insert into t(id, create_on) values
  (1, '2018-01-10'::date), 
  (2, '2018-01-20'::date);
  -- maybe have many other data

| sn | specified-date | expected-result         |
| 1  | 2018-01-09     | (1, '2018-01-10'::date) |
| 2  | 2018-01-10     | (1, '2018-01-10'::date) |
| 3  | 2018-01-11     | (1, '2018-01-10'::date) |
| 4  | 2018-01-19     | (1, '2018-01-10'::date) |
| 5  | 2018-01-20     | (2, '2018-01-20'::date) |
| 6  | 2018-01-21     | (2, '2018-01-20'::date) |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because you seem to want the most recent row one or before the date.  But if no such row exists, you want the earliest date in the table:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*
      from t
      where t.created_on <= :specified_date
      order by t.created_on desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     )
select tt.*  -- select most recent row before the date
from tt
union all
select t.*   -- otherwise select most oldest row
from t
where not exists (select 1 from tt)
order by t.created_on
fetch first 1 row only;
```

EDIT:

You can also handle this with a single query:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (t.created_on <= :specified_date) desc,  -- put older dates first
         (case when t.created_on <= :specified_date then created_on end) desc,
         created_on asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Although this looks simpler, it might actually be more expensive, because the query cannot make use of an index on `(created_on)`.  And, there is no `where` clause reducing the number of rows before sorting.